# Is it possible to inherit from a class below the first class? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example:

```
class Hello(Bye):
      def __init__(self):
          super().__init__()


class Bye:
     def __init__(self):
         pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
   Hello()
```

Is there a way to be able to do this? Basically i want to be able to inherit the Bye class into the Hello class, but because it is on the bottom I am not able to do so. I tried calling Bye before The Hello class at the bottom but it still did not work. Thanks!

Comment: No, there isn't. Class definition statements aren't declarations, python doesn't have declarations, they are executable pieces of code, you can think of them as syntactic sugar for calls to the thre-arg form of the `type` constructor (which returns a new class object).

Comment: Putting the cart before the horse.. why would you want to do that?

Comment: What possible reason would you have to do this? I'm genuinely curious!

Comment: Thanks guys, and @TheLazyScripter I was just curious to see if I can do that, i assume I can make another file and just import that class from that file right?

Comment: I understand. and yes, an import call is basically just a "copy/paste"! so it will work!

Comment: You can use a different file containing `Bye` and import it before defining `Hello`. You have to put thought into your modules, though. That file containing `Bye` can't also have circular dependencies on what is in the module with `Hello`. The two modules can't import each other.

Comment: Advise to refer to [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance)